# Angular UI Router refresh is taking to Parent State issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an app that uses angular-ui-router with html5mode(true). Everything seems to work fine when running and routing to other states. following are the states.

```
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/navigation-master");
$stateProvider
    .state('master', {
        url: "",
        views: {
            "@": {
                templateUrl: "content-master"
            },
            "nav-view": {
                templateUrl: "nav-content"
            }
        }
    })
    .state('master.content', {
        url: "/content/:pageId",
        views: {
            "content-view": {
                templateUrl: function ($stateParams) {
                    return 'content?pageId=' + $stateParams.pageId;
                }
            }
        },
        params: {extra: null}
    });

secApp.run(function ($transitions, $http, $templateCache ) {});
```

when i refresh the page while i'm currently in other routes(lets say master.content) it takes me back to navigation-master.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to set the url at `/` and not `` in your first state